# Use of present tense instead of past tense

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

I have noticed people increasingly using the present tense when talk about the past.

"I am going to the park when a dog jumps on me."
vs
"I was going to the park when a dog jumped on me."

I find it irritating for some reason but am I wrong?

Comment: [Not everyone](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/jul/28/historic-present-tense-past-john-humphrys) likes the [historical present](http://www.grammar.net/presentaspast), but it's perfectly legitimate, even [customary](http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2014/07/01/historical_present_the_tense_shows_up_in_jokes_dramatic_anecdotes_sportscasting.html) in some cases.

Comment: apologies for the duplicate but after searching I didn't find the existing question.

Comment: No worries! It's not always easy to find duplicates, especially if you're not familiar with the terminology, but this question will now be retained as a pointer to anyone who searches on the terms you use.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully there is some context that shows what they are doing: narrating the past as though it was being replayed, like a movie.  This is meant to make the story more vivid, although their mistake is that the images are much clearer to them, since they use pre-lingual memory.